# From where wp ecommerce is loading plugin theme files?

Tags: themes, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I updated my checkout page by updating the file which was in ....wp-ecommerce/wpsc-theme/wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php

It worked fine for a while, but now some of the changed states reverted to the previous state. Actually, I can even delete the file that I mentioned above, so it means wordpress is loading this file from somewhere else. Any ideas from where and what had happened? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The file should be located in your theme folder. If it's not found in the theme used, it uses the file in the wpsc-theme. The correct way to modify it is to copy the files from wpsc-theme to the active theme folder and apply modifications there.